# Preserving context in streams

Tags: node.js, rxjs

How do I preseve a context while not making it direct accessible in a stream?

For example:

I tried to model request/response with a stream that simply maps a response to a result. To enable a use like this:

```
requests
.filter(req => req.url == '/')
.map(req => {body: 'Hello, World!'})

requests
.filter(req => req.url == '/etc')
.map(req => {body: 'etc.'})
```

The problem I encountered was that the `http` module of Node.js got an interface like this:

```
server.on('request', (request, response) => ...)
```

So I would get a `request` object I could use in an `Observable`, but the `response` object is part of the context of a request, so the data I mapped a request to needs to led to the corresponding `response` object.

This would create a stream of requests only:

```
const requests = new Observable(o =>
  server.on('request', r => o.next(r))
)
```

And I could map the request data to anything I liked.

But when I subscribe to the resulting data, how do I get it back to the right response?

Can I somehow create a "private" stream for request/response, "publicly" map out the response object from it to get a request only stream and then map the results of this stream back to the original one?

Something like this:

```
const private = new Observable(o =>
  server.on('request', (request, response) => o.next({request, response})
)

const public = private.map(({request}) => request)

...

public.filter(r => r.url == '/').map(() => {body: 'Hello, World!'})

...

private
.matchUpWith(public)
.((privateData, publicData) =>
  privateData.response.end(publicData.body)
)
```

Comment: Hard to make any sense of that question. The proper way to explain a behavior is to specify it, i.e. input -> expected output. As you seem to have some ideas, it would be interesting to see what you tried (and did fail). You could use marble diagrams to help you write that specification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If think just subscribing to your `private` stream with the `public` stream would achieve what you want.

```js
const private$ = Rx.Observable.of(1,2,3,4,5);
const public$ = Rx.Subject.create({},private$);
    
public$.subscribe(i => console.log(i));
```

```html
<script src="https://npmcdn.com/@reactivex/rxjs@5.0.0-beta.11/dist/global/Rx.umd.js"></script>
```

Another try with two streams:

```js
const res = {
  send: (msg) => { console.log(msg); }
};

const one = { req: { url: '/', data: 'one' }, res };
const two = { req: { url: '/etc', data: 'two' }, res };
const three = { req: { url: '/', data: 'three' }, res };

const private$ = Rx.Observable.of(one,two, three)
  .concatMap(({req, res }) => {
    // public
    return Rx.Observable.of(req)
      .filter(r => r.url === '/')
      .map(r => ({body: `Hello, ${r.data}!`}))
      .map(p => ({ privateData: res, publicData:p }));
  })
  .subscribe(({privateData, publicData}) => {
    privateData.send(publicData.body);
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://npmcdn.com/@reactivex/rxjs@5.0.0-beta.11/dist/global/Rx.umd.js"></script>
```

---

*EDIT: Didn't really understood your question. But I leave my initial answer here:*

If I understood you correctly you want to create a "reactive" server by using RxJS to handle incoming requests. This should be a good starting point:

```
import * as Rx from 'rxjs';
import * as http from 'http';

const request$ = new Subject();
const server = http
  .createServer((req, res) => request$.next({ req, res }))
  .listen(3000);
```

Then you can `subscribe`/`filter`/... the requests with RxJS:

```
request$
  .filter(req => req.url == '/')
  .subscribe(({ res }) => {
    res.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/html"});
    res.end('Hello, World!');
  });
```

Comment: The problem is that I want to model my dataflow `requests.map(r => response)` but nodejs requires me to use a specific response object, tied to the request, to get my data to the right client.

Comment: I do not get what your saying, sorry. Could you try to explain further? Because the way node implemented the response/request is how HTTP works. You always will have a request response pair. But of course you can always pass down only the response object if you want to. But then you'll lose (potentially) important information.

Comment: When I map an array `[1,2,3].map(n => n * 2)` I map a number to a new number, that I create in the mapping. I wanted a behaviour like this for my http requests too, but the responses are already created so I couldn't just create a stream of requests and map them to responses that I create in the mapping, like with the numbers. I wanted an interface like `myFunc :: request -> response`

Comment: My idea was to simply put all requests into a stream, map them to my new data, and later pipe this data back into the right response.

Comment: But if put it that way a simple `.map` would suffice (or an [`expand`](http://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/transformation/expand.html)/[`concatMap`](http://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/transformation/concatmap.html)). Because you can do whatever you want with your input data. I do not see the gain in your approach. But I'll try to update my answer with another example :)

Comment: Added an example that uses a nested observable (=public).